# Show the Submit button, if and only if text (a character) is entered in a textbox else hide

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, events, dom-events

I am relatively new to the realm of programming and here is a beginner question. 
I have a textbox and a submit button in an aspx page, while trying to obtain some information from users on a page.

Now, I only want to show the submit button if a user enters text into the textbox else just hide it.

I thought that the onKeyDown or onKeyEvent should help me do it, but it doesnt work right. The button only shows after I enter 2 characters and does not hide unless I hit backspace again after having deleted the last character in the box. I do not want to use the `<input` tags and be able to work with the `<asp:Button` and Textbox tags.

CODE:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate> 

<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox" onKeyDown = "showAndHide()" runat="server" Height="95px" Width="340px" 
    CssClass="SuggestionTxtBox" TextMode="MultiLine" 
    ToolTip="Enter your Suggestion here...." BorderStyle="Ridge" 
    ontextchanged="TextBox_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>

<br />
<asp:Button ID="Button" runat="server" Text="Submit" 
    CssClass="SuggestionSubmitButton" onclick="Button_Click" 
    onclientclick="  " BackColor="#F5F5F5" Font-Size="13px" 
    ForeColor="#030756" Font-Bold="true" BorderStyle="None" Visible="False"  />
<br />
<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="SuggestionFootNote"                                                                           ForeColor="#030756"   Font-Italic="True" Font-Size="12px"></asp:Label>
<p>
&nbsp;</p>

<input type="text" id="input1" onkeydown="showAndHide();" /> 
<input type="submit" id="submit" style="display: none;" /> 


<script type="text/javascript">

inputOne = document.getElementById("input1");

inputSubmit = document.getElementById("submit");

function showAndHide() {
    if (inputOne.value == "") {
        inputSubmit.style.display = "none";
    }
    else {
        inputSubmit.style.display = "block";
    }
} 

</script> 
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please use `OnKeyUp` instead of `onkeydown`

If it is ASP.Net Button and Textbox then use

```
inputOne = document.getElementById("<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>");

inputSubmit = document.getElementById("<%= Button1.ClientID %>");
```

In the pageload

```
If(!IsPostBack)
{
    Button1.Attributes.Add("OnKeyUp","showAndHide();");
    Button1.Style.Add("display","none");
}
```

Comment: This works great now! But is there a way I can create the same functionality with my asp:button and asp:TextBox fields?

Comment: VS shows the following error when I try adding this line:  Button.Styles.Add"display","none");                                  Error 2 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button' does not contain a definition for 'Styles' and no extension method 'Styles' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Use `Style` not `Styles`.  It's also a good idea to do a bit of looking into the problem rather than just copying the code verbatim and hoping it works.  A simple web search, or glance at intellisense (or the MSDN documentation) would clarify the problem here.

Comment: Please Ignore the previous comment. It is 'Style' (corrected using intellisense) and not 'Styles'   I get a page compile error now though: "<%= TextBox.ClientId %>"     Textbox is my Textbox's ID. Am i missing something?

Comment: TextBox is a keyword, so please change it to TextBox1

Comment: Still get the same error. Thisis what I get: c:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\CONTROLTEMPLATES\VisualWebPartProject1\VisualWebPart1\VisualWebPart1UserControl.ascx(56,54): error CS0117: 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox' does not contain a definition for 'ClientId'